# Segmentation fault in Swift compiler when converting to Swift 4 syntax Ask

Tags: converters, swift4

I have some Swift code that was written in Swift 3.2, and I just attempted to use the automatic syntax converter in Xcode 9.0 to update to Swift 4.0.

but getting the error:
any ideas what this mean?

```
0  swift                    0x000000011095ddba PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
    1  swift                    0x000000011095d1f6 SignalHandler(int) + 662
    2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fffcb4fcb3a _sigtramp + 26
    3  swift                    0x00000001106f6f3d llvm::BitstreamCursor::readRecord(unsigned int, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<unsigned long long>&, llvm::StringRef*) + 637
    4  swift                    0x000000010df96f70 swift::migrator::updateCodeAndEmitRemap(swift::CompilerInstance*, swift::CompilerInvocation const&) + 960
    5  swift                    0x000000010d2cd6a5 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 1925
    6  swift                    0x000000010d2cb6b4 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7716
    7  swift                    0x000000010d2805d8 main + 12248
    8  libdyld.dylib            0x00007fffcb2ed235 start + 1
    9  libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000056 start + 886124066
```

Comment: Look at the detailed error view by clicking on the error in the issue navigator. There is probably more specific information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic syntax converter go trough once I apply another warning "apply recommended settings", it changed swift module optimization.